# Subdivided icosahedron points do not lie on circumscribed sphere

Tags: geometry

How do we subdivide an icosahedron so that the new vertices created on each subdivision also lie on the circumscribed sphere. i.e. have the same radius as the original icosahedron?

If we just create a new vertex as being the half way point between each paired vertex, they do not have the same radius. For example, for a icosahedron of radius 1 the original vertices are:

```
(0, 0.525731, -0.850651)
(0, 0.525731, 0.850651)
(0, -0.525731, 0.850651)
(-0.525731, 0.850651, 0)
(-0.525731, -0.850651, 0)
(0.525731, 0.850651, 0)
(0.525731, -0.850651, 0)
(0, -0.525731, -0.850651)
(0.850651, 0, 0.525731)
(-0.850651, 0, 0.525731)
(-0.850651, 0, -0.525731)
(0.850651, 0, -0.525731)
```

And after subdivision some examples of new vertices are:

```
(-0.783297, 0.484104, 0.299193)
(-0.968208, -1.57166e-15, 0)
```

who's euclidean distance is ~ $0.968208$

Answer (score 1):

You should be taking the midpoint of the arc of great circle joining the two vertices rather than the midpoint of the straight line interval joining them.  The easiest way to get the right point is simply to normalize the half-way point (i.e., divide the "half-way" vector by its length).

Comment: Of course, this only works for the midpoint; if you want to uniformly subdivide multiple times per face then you can't simply take e.g. the 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 points along the edge and normalize them (the angles for the non-central points won't be correct).  Instead you should spherically interpolate (_slerp_) between the two vertices by the appropriate amount.

Comment: @user72694 so if I normalize them, then multiply by desired radius, it should be the correct coordinate. interesting... I will give this a try and accept if works. Thanks